# How to configure VS Code so it won't close console after program run

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, console-application

When I run my program via VS Code it: console opens, program gets input and after that console immediately closes.

1. I know that if I had had regular Visual Studio, I would have just pressed Ctrl+F5 (but I have VS Code, so it doesn't work)
2. Methods like putting `getc()` at the last line of the code are as for me "dirty" so they are not the solution.

I think there can be kind of configuration of `launch.json` or `task.json` which will make the console remain open after the program ends.

Comment: Place a breakpoint at the end of main.

Comment: Or maybe there isn't. Visual Studio 2019 RC is the first VS to add that option as far as I remember. So on Windows I use `system("pause");`

Answer (score 0):

You can add *cin.get();* at end of your main method, this will wait until you press a button.
You can also run the program from the VSCode terminal so the output will be on the terminal also after the program ends.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I got it, but I need to be able run program pressing Ctrl+F5 is VS Code

Comment: To make the console remain open after the program ends you can add cin.get(); at end of your main method.
For using Ctrl+F5 I think you can use tasks and key binding
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings